# migrating from global mixins in vue2 to global composables in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-mixin

I"m porting my new app from vue2 to vue3. Since mixins are not recommended way of reusing code in vue3, Im trying to convert them into composable.

I've 2 mixins (methods) `__(key)` and `__n(key, number)`  in `mixins/translate.js` which will translate any word into the app's locale.

```js
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        /**
         * Translate the given key.
         */
        __(key, replace = {}) {
           // logic

            return translation
        }
```

Now this is how I converted it as

Composables/translate.js

```js
export function __(key, replace = {}) {
  // logic

    return translation
}
```

and since I need these functions to be accessbile in every component without explicitly importing. I'm importing it in `app.js`

```
import {__, __n} from '@/Composables/translate.js';
```

#### Questions

1. __() is not accessible in every component.  How to make this function accessible in every component without explicit import
2. Is this the right of doing things?

These functions are required essentially in every component, declaring them in every component is impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1, You can put it into the globalProperties object

```js
import {__, __n} from '@/Composables/translate.js';

const app = createApp(AppComponent);
app.config.globalProperties.__ = __;
app.config.globalProperties.__n = __n;
```

#2, though opinion based, importing for every component that needs it would be my preferred way.

Comment: I was using inertia app. The correct way to set config.globalProperties in inertia-vue3 is described here: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/287#issuecomment-890816656